# How to ignore nested fields from parent class?

Tags: java, jackson, json-deserialization

I have a JSON model with A child property that has lots of fields which I would like to ignore. For example

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "preference": {
        "subproperty1": "dummy",
        "subproperty2": "dummy",
        "subproperty3": "dummy",
        ...
        "subproperty40": "dummy",
    },
    "property1": "dummy",
    "property2": "dummy",
    ...
    "property30": "dummy",
}
```

My expected deserialized result would be something look like

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "preference": {
        "subproperty1": "dummy",
        "subproperty2": "dummy",
    },
    "property1": "dummy",
    "property2": "dummy"
}
```

Meaning I would like to ignore lots of fields in my current and nested class, I know there is a `@JsonIgnoreProperties` to use such as

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"name", "property3", "property4", ..., "property30"})
@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_EMPTY)
protected static class MixInMyClass {

}
...
objectMapper.getDeserializationConfig().addMixInAnnotations(MyClass.class, MixInMyClass.class);
```

- Question1: how could I ignore my nested fields (e.g, subproperty3, subproperty4... subproperty30) in "preference" on top of `MixInMyClass`?
- Question2: is there any easier way like a `JsonRequired` which plays as the opposite behavior and only allows certain needed fields in? So I don't need to have lots of unwanted fields as in jsonIgnore, but just few items like (id, property1, property2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply fix this by annotating `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true).`

Here is an example,

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class YouMainClass {
    private Integer id;
    private Preference preference;
    private String property1;
    private String property2;

    // getters & setters
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class Preference {
    private String property1;
    private String property2;

    // getters & setters
}
```

Use this `YouMainClass` to deserialize the JSON. All the unknow/unwanted properties will be ignored when deserializing.

Answer (score 0):

1. To my knowledge no. You need to place the `@JsonIgnoreProperties` in nested classes as well.
2. Take a look at [JSON Views][1]. With it, you can tell which properties to include in each view. You could have 1 view:

```java
public class Views {
    public static class Public {
    }
}
```

Then in your model you would need to annotate the properties you want to be avialble with `@JsonView(Views.Public.class)`.
Finally, in your endpoints, you would use `@JsonView(Views.Public.class)`.

Comment: so I need to create 2 MixIn classes and add annotation on each, but how could I connect those 2 MixIn classes together?